# (iOS) Exit the app programmatically.

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to exit the app at the time of no internet connection at launch time.I have used exit(0) to exit the app giving alert of **NO Internet Connection** to user.I heard it is not standard way to perform as app store rejects the app saying it as a bug and count it in crash.

Comment: This would be against Apple's guidelines. I suggest finding a different way to inform the user of the issue and letting them exit the app

Comment: @BJHStudios The app is giving alert of NO INTERNET CONNECTION and the user itself killing the app on clicking of OK button.Please suggest me another method the user should use to exit the app.

Comment: It is not a good idea idea to ever force exit an app. Not a good user experience. If the user *wants* to leave the app, they can at any time. If your app absolutely cannot function without internet connection, provide some UI, tell them they need internet connection, and provide a button to retry once they think they have internet connection again. However, in a majority of cases, even if you can't do the core function of your app, you can cache some stuff locally and give the user *something* to do.

Comment: The user has the ability to exit or force close your app at any time. Forcing an app crash will never be an experience Apple approves of, though it may slip by their review process.

Comment: @k.kishore, see the answer. It's a good one. Also, always remember to ask yourself a question: How do others handle this?

Comment: @k.kishore You should be able to call `exit(0)` from your app, provided you have `Foundation` imported. However, as the others have said above, you **should not** be doing this for an App Store app–it's a poor user experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @BJHStudios said, it is against Apple guidelines to force an app to close programmatically. As a user, it would also be an unwelcome feature.

As an example, if I opened your app and didn't have an internet connection, I might simply need to turn on wifi or disable airplane mode. It would be better in my opinion to be told there is no connection and be presented with a retry option so I could perhaps fix my connection without getting bumped back to the home screen.

Something like an infinite retry option is what many game makers use for online only games, and it doesn't cause any problems on submission.

Just food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html

So, you do not call the exit function if you want to get through Apple's app review.